# Error: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, django-2.2

I have a strange error. I check my code over and over and can't seems to find the error. I write login function, works just fine, added logout function, works fine too. But when I tried to run the basic url, where I should go to the home page (http://192.168.2.80:8000/), it gives me this error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found.
> 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I added decorators too, to restrict the pages, but can' understand why is the error.

**viwes.py:**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

def loginPage(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if request.GET.get('next'):
                return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
            else:
                return redirect('feedback:index')

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'feedback'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),

    path('', views.index, name="index"),  
]
```

**the root urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'feedback'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('feedback.urls')),
]
```

**I also added these lines into my settings.py:**

```
LOGIN_URL = "login"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'
```

Anyone can see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `app_name = 'feedback` in your `urls.py`. Therefore you should include the `feedback` namespace with `LOGIN_URL`, like you already do in `redirect('feedback:index')`.

```
LOGIN_URL = "feedback:login"
```